# how should I call an external program from inside a C program

Tags: c

I am currently working on moving some bash scripts over to C, and one of them call's an external python script, so for instance ./remoteclient01a.py "remotecommand player /something something"

```
./remoteclient01a.py "remotecommand player /something something"
```

and Ive been looking for a way to execute this command in C, but Im not really sure as to which I should use, being that System() seems to be the best one, but then a few pages say that it is a bad choice in some cases, so if someone could recommend a method to do this I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: I'm curious and not being critical as to why you're not moving the bash scripts to Python.

Comment: oh I am moving the bash scripts to python, its just that some of them call a python script as well, the python script uses a few custom libraries to interface with a python based multiplexer, so would be a lot of work to rewrite the python script itself, I plan to do so in the future though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only portable ways to do this in C are `system` and `popen`. The function `popen` allows you to read output from the command.

Answer (score 0):

- For simple problems in unixish environments try popen().

From the man page

```
The popen() function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking and involking the
shell.
```

- There are other means to call an external program in C. See the following tutorial explaining all the ways :

  [Executing programs with C(Linux)](http://www.gidforums.com/t-3369.html)